# Solve for x in matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Solve for $X$

$$
A^{-1} \,  X \, B-B=-A^{-1} \, X
$$

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}
\quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Is $X$ a vector or some matrix?

Comment: You will receive better answers if you show some effort about what you have tried so far, instead of just asking someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

$$A^{-1}XB-B=-A^{-1}X \\XB-AB=-X \\ X(B+I)=AB \\ X=(AB)(B+I)^{-1}$$

Comment: That´s what I got, but when my teacher did it he got X=(B+1)^{-1} \, (AB), so I got very confused

Comment: If i solve $$(AB)(B+1)^{-1}$$ I get
$$ \begin{bmatrix}3&-3/2\\0&3/2\end{bmatrix}$$
but if I solve  $$(B+1)^{-1}(AB)$$ I get
$$ \begin{bmatrix}9/2&-3/2\\-3&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Aren´t those different?

Comment: @BUENO yes they are different and your computations are correct. The argument of user236182 that they are the same because they are $2\times 2$ matrices is wrong. However, his solution is correct. So, I guess that your teacher made a mistake.